# Estimation of marginal and conditional frequency distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

The joint frequency distribution of two discrete random variables,  and , is given in the following table:

[image]

Can anybody help me how to find the marginal frequency distributions of  and  and the conditional frequency distributions of  given =1, and of  given =2?

Comment: Hint: To find the marginal distribution of x just sum up the values of the columns at the corresponding row. Comprehensible?

Comment: Leave a comment if you have no questions anymore.

Comment: Sorry I have problem with internet. Yes I will do it. And second one ? Also sum ?

Comment: The sum for the denominator. For instance f(x|y=1): The relevant values are in the first column. For the denominator you sum up all values of the column Then for x=1 the value is $\frac{0.1}{0.1+0.05+0.02+0.02}$. $P(X=1|Y=1)=\frac{0.1}{0.19}$ and therefore $P(X=2|Y=1)=\frac{0.05}{0.19}$, ...

Comment: Thank you.I will check.

Comment: You´re welcome. Feel free to ask if there is still a lack of clarity.